# Compound poisson process invariant measure

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\rho$ be a probability measure in $\mathbb{R}$, $(N_t)$ a standar Poisson process and $(X_i) \stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \rho$. Then $$Z_t = \sum_{n=1}^{N_t} X_n $$ is call a compound poisson process and is a markov process with infinitesimal generator $$A\phi (x)= \int_{\mathbb{R}}( \phi(x+z) - \phi(x)) \rho(dz)$$

is posible to find a stationary distribution for this markov process ?

every help will be appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't we expect $Z_t$ to spread out over time? How could there be a stationary distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process $Z$ does have at least one *invariant measure*; namely Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$. Also, if $\gamma\in\Bbb R$ is such that $\Bbb E[e^{-\gamma Z_t}]=1$ for one $t>0$ (equivalently, for all $t>0$) then $\mu(dx) = e^{\gamma x}\,dx$ is also an invariant measure. The most general invariant measure for $Z$ is a positive linear combination of these two. None of these measures has finite total mass.